# Conditional parameters within LESS mixin

Tags: css, less

### Problem

I've created the following mixin:

```
.type(@style;@mb) {
    & when (@style = hero) {
        margin-bottom: @mb;
        font-size: 2.625rem;
        line-height: 1.238095238;
    }
}
```

Now this does *mostly* what I want. The problem I am having is sometimes I will want to declare a `@mb` value, but many times I will not. In those instances I will want to fallback to a pre-determined value for each `@style` parameter.

For example:

- For `hero`, `@mb` default is `margin-bottom: 1.25rem;`
- For `page`, `@mb` default is `margin-bottom: 1.125rem;`
- etc

---

### Desired Outcome

The desired outcome is as follows:

```
.sample-class-01 { .type(hero); }
.sample-class-02 { .type(page,0); }
```

and I would get the following output:

```
.sample-class-01 { 
    margin-bottom: 1.25rem;
    font-size: 2.625rem;
    line-height: 1.238095238;
}
.sample-class-02 {
    margin-bottom: 0;
    font-size: 2rem;
    line-height: 1.3125;
}
```

---

### How do I create this mixin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just make the mixin specialization/overloading for each style set:

```
.type(hero, @mb: 1.25rem) {
    margin-bottom: @mb;
    font-size: 2.625rem;
    line-height: 1.238095238;
}

.type(not-a-hero, @mb: 2.22rem) {
    margin-bottom: @mb;
    font-size: 3.333rem;
    line-height: 4.444444444;
}

// etc.
```

Ref.:

- [Argument
  Pattern-matching](http://lesscss.org/features/#mixins-parametric-feature-pattern-matching)
- [Mixins with Multiple
  Parameters](http://lesscss.org/features/#mixins-parametric-feature-mixins-with-multiple-parameters)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
.type(@style; @mb: '') {
    & when (@style = hero) {
      font-size: 42px;              // 42px
      line-height: 52px;       // 52px

      & when not (@mb = '') { margin-bottom: @mb; }
      & when (@mb = '') { margin-bottom: 1.25rem; }
    }

    & when (@style = footer) {
      font-size: 22px;              // 42px
      line-height: 32px;       // 52px

      & when not (@mb = '') { margin-bottom: @mb; }
      & when (@mb = '') { margin-bottom: 1.125rem; }
    }
}

.sample-class-1 { .type(hero); }
.sample-class-2 { .type(hero,0); }
.sample-class-3 { .type(hero,3rem); }


.sample-class-4 { .type(footer); }
.sample-class-5 { .type(footer,0); }
.sample-class-6 { .type(footer,3rem); }
```

Should compile to:

```
.sample-class-1 {
  font-size: 42px;
  line-height: 52px;
  margin-bottom: 1.25rem;
}
.sample-class-2 {
  font-size: 42px;
  line-height: 52px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
.sample-class-3 {
  font-size: 42px;
  line-height: 52px;
  margin-bottom: 3rem;
}
.sample-class-4 {
  font-size: 22px;
  line-height: 32px;
  margin-bottom: 1.125rem;
}
.sample-class-5 {
  font-size: 22px;
  line-height: 32px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
.sample-class-6 {
  font-size: 22px;
  line-height: 32px;
  margin-bottom: 3rem;
}
```

[Less2css link](http://less2css.org/#%7B%22less%22%3A%22.type(%40style%3B%20%40mb%3A%20'')%20%7B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%26%20when%20(%40style%20%3D%20hero)%20%7B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20font-size%3A%2042px%3B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%2042px%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20line-height%3A%2052px%3B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%2052px%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%26%20when%20not%20(%40mb%20%3D%20'')%20%7B%20margin-bottom%3A%20%40mb%3B%20%7D%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%26%20when%20(%40mb%20%3D%20'')%20%7B%20margin-bottom%3A%201.25rem%3B%20%7D%5Cn%20%20%20%20%7D%5Cn%20%20%5Cn%20%20%20%20%26%20when%20(%40style%20%3D%20footer)%20%7B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20font-size%3A%2022px%3B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%2042px%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20line-height%3A%2032px%3B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%2052px%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%26%20when%20not%20(%40mb%20%3D%20'')%20%7B%20margin-bottom%3A%20%40mb%3B%20%7D%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%26%20when%20(%40mb%20%3D%20'')%20%7B%20margin-bottom%3A%201.125rem%3B%20%7D%5Cn%20%20%20%20%7D%5Cn%7D%5Cn%5Cn.sample-class-1%20%7B%20.type(hero)%3B%20%7D%5Cn.sample-class-2%20%7B%20.type(hero%2C0)%3B%20%7D%5Cn.sample-class-2%20%7B%20.type(hero%2C3rem)%3B%20%7D%5Cn%5Cn%5Cn.sample-class-1%20%7B%20.type(footer)%3B%20%7D%5Cn.sample-class-2%20%7B%20.type(footer%2C0)%3B%20%7D%5Cn.sample-class-2%20%7B%20.type(footer%2C3rem)%3B%20%7D%5Cn%5Cn%22%7D)

Comment: Overbloat warning. See the code in my comment of another answer.

Comment: @seven-phases-max how is this answer different from the gist you provided? Seems like the same idea.

Comment: @Hynes Same idea - 3x less code (not even counting the readability).

Comment: @seven-phases-max you should post your example as an answer then